# Remove Title and White Space in Twenty Twenty theme

Tags: customization

I just redid my site using Twenty Twenty and it looks 'okay' but at the top of every page there is like a 24pt block that says "Add Title" in Bold. It creates a lot of white space between where the Site Identity logo/tagline is at the top (and the Menu); and where content begins below it.

I've scoured the posts and come up with several reoccurring suggestions for adding CSS code under Themes/Customizing/Additional CSS. Here is what I found in other questions:

.entry .entry-header {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.site-header {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.entry-content, {
    margin-top: 0;
}

..None of these works to remove the white space, or the 'Add Title' on every page when I open and existing page or add a new one.

Again, using Twenty Twenty theme, just updated to ver 1.3 with the 5.4x security update (as of 5/18/20).

Comment: Are you trying to remove titles and the "Add Title" field entirely, or just trying to adjust the space around them?

Comment: as your question is theme specific, try asking in https://wordpress.org/support/theme/twentytwenty/

Comment: yes, I am trying to remove the field completely (and in doing so, hopefully reducing the white space that it occupies. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am trying to remove the field completely, and hopefully the white space with it while doing so.  Thanks!